# Converting string to byte[] and back to string between client and server

Tags: java, string, web-services, servlets, character-encoding

I'm sending a text to a webservice but converting to bytes first and on the server side after receiving I want to change the bytes back to a string. I have been able to convert to bytes but having trouble converting back to a string. I've looked at a lot of tutorials on SO and so far none seem to work.

Here is the client application

```
try {   
        String text = "holiday";
        byte[] byte_text = text.getBytes();
        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpGet request = new HttpGet();
        URI link = new URI("http://192.165.1.3:8080/HelloWorld/hello?text="+byte_text);
        request.setURI(link);
        HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);

    } catch (Exception e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Here is what I have done on the client side

```
    byte[] why = req.getParameter("text").getBytes();
    String text = new String(why);
    System.out.println(text);
```

I have tried using the UTF and ASCII encodings when I call the getbyte and new String functions but I still get the result in bytes like this [B@405c0ce0

Comment: I'm with JB; what are you actually trying to accomplish?

Comment: Why? Appending a byte array to a String doesn't do what you think it does, and appending a String *does* do what you think the former should do. What's the point of the conversion?

Answer (score 3):

When you execute `"http://192.168.0.3:8080/HelloWorld/hello?text=" + byte_text`, the `toString()` method is called on the byte array to transform it into a String, and append this String to the URL. The `toString()` method of `byte[]` return `"[B@"` followed by the hash code of the object.

That said, your code really makes no sense. You have a String and want to append it to an URL. What's the point of transformiong the String to a byte array and then the byte array back into a String?

What would make sense would be to use `java.net.URLEncoder` to make sure all the special characters are correctly encoded and that the result of the encoding is safe to be appended as a query string parameter.

Comment: The app I am designing will have to handle lots of different languages which have special characters. I noticed that when I sent the text as a string the special characters were changed into something else so I decided to try using bytes instead. Is there any other way i can get around this?